# What format for scanf will read in the example input line?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm working on an old C program and ran into a problem with `scanf`. I have been experimenting for many hours but still cannot get `scanf` to read a particular line.

The line being read in is:

> `01/05\t\t840.81\tvisa payment (online)\tAFCU\n`

The C code using `scanf` is:

```
sscanf(lineIn, "%d/%d %f %[A-Z\(\)a-z0-9]s\t%[A-Za-z0-9]s",
       &month, &year, &amt, &item, &supplier);
```

This line scans the `month`, `year`, `amt` and `item` variables correctly and the values can be verified. But no matter what format I used at the end, I cannot get the value of `supplier` to be read in.

Can anyone suggest a format that will scan in all of the variables?

Comment: The format string `%[A-Z\(\)a-z0-9]s` makes little sense.  The author probably thought that this was an `s` conversion specifier and did not realize that it is a `%[]` conversion specifier followed by a literal `s`.  Which is to say that `scanf` will stop if the next character in the stream is not a literal `s`.  Which will always be true.  (The `s` would be consumed in the conversion)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, William. A busy weekend coming up, so I will review and fix my code next week.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot get the value <strike>if</strike> of supplier

Scanning stopped on the incorrect `s`. [@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941349/what-format-for-scanf-will-read-in-the-example-input-line/74941890#comment132249387_74941349).

Lack of a `' '` in `%[A-Z\(\)a-z0-9]` contributes to not scanning all of the item.

---

**Do not use `"%s"` nor `"%[]"` without a *Width*.**

Use a width one less than the array count.

**`s` is wrong after a `%[]`**

Drop the `s` in `"%[A-Z\(\)a-z0-9]s"`.  `"%[A-Z\(\)a-z0-9]"` and `"%s"` are separate scan directives.

**Do not use undefined escapes**

`\(` and and `\)` are not defined.

**`float` with money is marginally OK**

Better as `double`.  *Money* has a whole hosts of issues too.

**Check conversion success**

**Do not use the address of any array for `%[]`**

Pass the address of the first element of the array.
This implies compiling done without all warnings enabled.
Save time.  Enable all warnings.

**Allow spaces in `item[]`, `supplier[]`**

> ... the space in the `%100[A-Za-z0-9 ]` conversion has a different meaning from the space before `%n`: a space in a scan set matches the space character whereas a space elsewhere in the format string matches any white space characters, including TAB and newline. [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941349/what-format-for-scanf-will-read-in-the-example-input-line/74941890?noredirect=1#comment132250140_74941890)

---

- I recommend using `" %n"` to detect complete conversion success.
- Be generous, allow white-space between tokens.  `%d`, `%f`, `%s` already allow leading white-space.  `%[]` does not.

```
int main(void) {
  const char *lineIn = "01/05\t\t840.81\tvisa payment (online)\tAFCU\n";

  int month, year;
  double amt;
  char item[90 + 1];
  char supplier[100 + 1];

  // sscanf(lineIn,"%d/%d %f %[A-Z\(\)a-z0-9]s\t%[A-Za-z0-9]s",
  //    &month,&year,&amt,&item,&supplier);

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(lineIn, "%d /%d%lf %90[A-Z()a-z0-9 ] %100[A-Za-z0-9 ] %n", //
      &month, &year, &amt, item, supplier, &n);
  if (n == 0 || lineIn[n]) {
    puts("Failed");
  } else {
    puts("Success");
  }

}
```